ReordableListView.builder is not working with dynamic parameters for the itemBuilder
I am using ReordableListView to render a list of MemoItem widgets that can be ordered.
My setup is working nicely with the list, but I need to add a customization to the rendered widgets so that if the MemoItem is "selected" (is being dragged), it will have some change in ui (like a different border).
What I tried to do is putting selectedIndex in the state and updating with the onReoderStart and on ReorderEnd. I printed all I could print and it's working, but the ReordableListView builder for some reason is NOT PASSING the correct value to the widget. isSelected is true when entering the widget, but false if I print it inside the widget.
It's like the widget is constant and not rebuilding when the parameters change. The tree is rebuilding when I drag the items of course, but the items inside the builder stay "constant".
I checked that the keys are unique.
Here's my code (edited the not-relevant parts):
class MemoPage extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const MemoPage({super.key});

  @override
  ConsumerState<MemoPage> createState() => _MemoPageState();
}

class _MemoPageState extends ConsumerState<MemoPage> {
  int? selectedIndex;


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final allMemo = ref.watch(memoListProvider.select((state) => state.allMemos));
    ref.watch(memoListProvider);
    final bool isMemoListEmpty = allMemo.isEmpty;
    final bool isLoading = ref.watch(memoListProvider.select((state) => state.isLoading));

  

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: CustomColors.lightGrey,
      body: Builder(builder: (context) {
        return ReorderableListView.builder(
            itemCount: allMemo.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              bool isSelected = selectedIndex == index;
              if (isSelected) {
                print('selected index: $index');
                
            // It is correctly printing selected index = n when the widget is selected
              }
              return MemoItem(
                key: ValueKey('${allMemo[index].id}'),
                memo: allMemo[index],
            
            // It is not correctly passing the value of isSelected to the MemoItem widget. 
            // If I print isSelected inside the MemoItem widget, it's always returning 
            // false.

                isSelected: isSelected,
              );
            },
            
            onReorderEnd: (index) {
              selectedIndex = null;
            },
            onReorderStart: (index) {
              selectedIndex = index;
            },
            
      }),
    );
  }

}

In my MemoItemWidget (edited for simplicity)
class MemoItem extends StatelessWidget {
  const MemoItem({super.key, required this.isSelected, required this.memo});
    // memo object
  final bool isSelected;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print(isSelected);
    return const SizedBox();
  }
}

isSelected is always printing false.
Am I missing something? Is this default behaviour for this widget?

You need to call setState inside onReorderStart/End to have it actually rebuild. At the moment you are just assigning the variable but never triggering it to rebuild.

It's the same with setState unfortunately, I removed it for simplicity. The rebuild is being triggered every time you select an item and drag it, and I checked that isSelected is true (so it's rebuilding) when it's "entering" the widget as a parameter.

You don't need to manually track the dragged item's index to customize its appearance. The ReorderableListView.builder provides a built-in proxyDecorator callback, which allows you to modify the appearance of the widget being dragged without extra state management.
For example, if you want to add a solid red border around the dragged item, you can implement the proxyDecorator like this:
proxyDecorator: (widget, index, animation) {
  return Material(
    type: MaterialType.transparency,
    child: DecoratedBox(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(
          width: 2,
          color: Colors.red,
        ),
      ),
      child: widget,
    ),
  );
}

Additionally, if you want to customize more than just the border—such as changing the content or style of the dragged item—you can still use the proxyDecorator to make these changes. Here's a full example where the background color and text of the item change when it's being dragged:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const ReorderableApp());

class ReorderableApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const ReorderableApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('ReorderableListView Example')),
        body: const ReorderableExample(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ReorderableExample extends StatefulWidget {
  const ReorderableExample({super.key});

  @override
  State<ReorderableExample> createState() => _ReorderableExampleState();
}

class _ReorderableExampleState extends State<ReorderableExample> {
  final List<int> _items = List<int>.generate(50, (int index) => index);

  Widget _buildItem({required int index, required bool isBeingDragged}) {
    return ListTile(
      key: ValueKey(_items[index]),
      title: Text(isBeingDragged
          ? "Item ${_items[index]} is being dragged!"
          : 'Item ${_items[index]}'),
      tileColor: isBeingDragged ? Colors.lime : Colors.white,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ReorderableListView.builder(
      itemCount: _items.length,
      itemBuilder: (_, index) => _buildItem(index: index, isBeingDragged: false),
      onReorder: (oldIndex, newIndex) {
        setState(() {
          if (oldIndex < newIndex) newIndex -= 1;
          final int item = _items.removeAt(oldIndex);
          _items.insert(newIndex, item);
        });
      },
      proxyDecorator: (child, index, animation) => Material(
        type: MaterialType.transparency,
        child: _buildItem(index: index, isBeingDragged: true),
      ),
    );
  }
}


For more details, refer to the official ReorderableListView documentation.

Unfortunately this does not account for  a widget that has a padding and a margin. I don't want to decorate the whole draggable widget, but something "inside" that widget

@PawnBreak I added another example that covers your need to change inside the child widget that is being dragged. If you found the answer helpful, you can mark it as accepted by clicking the checkmark next to the answer. This helps others who might have the same question. Thanks!
